# meaning of で言っても?

Tags: grammar, particles

Found this sentence:

> 人生経験で言っても、十数年引きこもっていた俺よりも、彼の方が上なんだろう。

Is it a grammatical structure or am I missing something?

Comment: What's your best understand of what this says?  Granted you might be uncertain of this particular grammatical point, but still what's your guess about the rest of it and how you think this portion might fit in?

Comment: What I understood is that something along the lines of "Even talking from/with life experience". Also my brain somehow relates this "で言っても" to "と言っても". But is the verb that bugs me tbh.

Answer (score 2):

This で言っても can be understood as

- で : which aspect is being talked about. [基準を表す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7/#jn-148951)
- 言って : te/continuative form (but see note)
- も : also

Combined, *also speaking in terms of hands-on/real life experience*...

An implication is that *he* is superior to the speaker in some other terms.

**Notes**

Removing も=*also* would give 人生経験で言って, which is a bit unnatural. で言うと will be more usual. I don't have a good explanation for this.

ても in と言っても is independently covered in grammar (e.g. [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82-to-ittemo-meaning/)) and is used for connecting contrary-ish clauses.